# Which sorting algorithm(s) does MySQL use?

Tags: mysql, sorting

If MySQL is to run a query `select * from table order by datetime`, where `datetime` is a datetime column, on a table with >10 million rows, which sorting algorithm does it use?

Comment: is there an index on the field?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details in the documentation on [Order By Optimisation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Essentially the MySQL engine will consider using an index, if a suitable one is available, and it is estimated that using it would be beneficial to the performance.

If no such index is selected, then a so-called "filesort" operation will be performed, which -- despite its name -- might very well execute completely in memory. But it may also use temporary files to swap in/out partitions that are (to be) sorted, and to merge sorted partitions into bigger ones.

In-memory sorting is performed with Quick Sort. You can find a `mf_qsort.c` file in [the source files in the mysys folder](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en//mysys-directory.html).

A `datetime` is represented by [5 to 8 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html) (depending on whether second fractions are used), and sorting by it is no different than sorting a `bigint` which also [occupies 8 bytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

It works if your column datetime has declared index.  Without index, your query will be slower on on millions of records. If you are using it alone for reporting, you should be fine.

In general usage (fast interaction with many users) this is not a good practise. It is recommended to use additional conditions on WHERE clause to further filter your data. As well as having additional index on columns used in WHERE clause.  LIMIT clause also helps.